# Can I use the Java SDK for the Okta API to check for the existence of an Okta Session created by a user sign-on?

Tags: java, okta, okta-api

I am working on putting an internal Java web application behind Okta for authentication. In order to do this I want to use API calls to check for a current Okta Session.

The Session API provides methods for validating a session via a sessionToken. However, this means that the Session must also be created within the application by calling the Authentication API and then using the Session API to create a session and receive said sessionToken.

I would like to check for a current session that was **created by a user signing into Okta prior to visiting the custom application**. Then, I would check if the status of the Session is ACTIVE. I could then redirect them to the correct area of my application. Otherwise, if the status was not ACTIVE, I would redirect them to my company's Okta sign-in page.

Is there a way to leverage the API to check the status of an existing Okta Session that was created by an Okta sign-on (**not** by a previous Session API call)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by using the /sessions/me API in a cookie-compliant client (such as a browser).

You can look at how I perform that check to display the Okta sign in widget in my code sample available at https://github.com/rlondner/okta-oidc-spa-authjs-siw.

I hope this helps!